# Why does getting a URL from the US Patent & Trademark Office return an SSL error in Livecode?

Tags: https, livecode, geturl

A Livecode script:

get URL "https://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws-and-regulations/patent-term-extension/patent-terms-extended-under-35-usc-156"

Winds up with the following in "the result":

```
 tsneterr: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

I tried setting **libURLSetSSLVerification** to both true and false, but got the same error each time. Any ideas why this is happening, and is there a solution?

Comment: Are you using a commercial edition of LiveCode or do you stick with the opensource edition? There is no tsNet in the opensource edition.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `tsNetVerifySSLPeer false`

instead of `libURLSetSSLVerification false`.

It is probable that `libURLSetSSLVerification` has no effect on tsNET, since libURL uses a completely different library from tsNet.

Comment: Thanks, Devin, for your response. I just discovered that the URL I had been using successfully for a number of years is now being redirected to: https://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws/patent-term-extension/patent-terms-extended-under-35-usc-156. It happens so quickly that it is hardly noticeable when using a web browser. When I eliminated the "-and-regulations" from the URL my script was using, the error disappeared! In the meantime, I learned a lot about tsnet trying to use your suggestion. So it was time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

I put your question to the developer of the tsNet library, Charles Warwick. He sent me this answer, which I am posting for your information. Hope you find it helpful.

> This seems to be an issue which has come up a few times over the years with the curl library.

> It appears to be specific to when curl is compiled on OS X to use the Mac SSL library, rather than OpenSSL.

> I am guessing you are trying this on a Mac?

> I have tested a build of tsNet under OS X that uses OpenSSL instead, and the issue goes away.  Unfortunately, building tsNet to use OpenSSL on Mac would mean that it no longer uses the OS X certificate store for verifying SSL certificates.